# Total Sum of Vlookup CSV'd Array

Tags: excel, csv, split, sum, vlookup

So I've been trying for the past hour or so to figure this one out but I can't seem to get it right...

**To start, here is the formula I am working with:**

```
=ArrayFormula(join(", ",vlookup(transpose(trim(split(V:V,","))),Costs!N:O,2,0)))
```

**The items in column V contain values based on user choices, there are up to 10 choices but for examples sake they may appear as such:**

```
Apple, Banana, Carrot, Date, Elderberry
Apple, Banana
Apple, Date, Elderberry
Carrot, Date
```

**Over in the Costs sheet in column N to O we have the following values:**

```
Apple 1

Banana 2

Carrot 3

Date 4

Elderberry 5
```

**Now with the given formula above my output in the cell that contains the formula varies depending on the initial values in column V, but as an example using the first cell value:**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

The issue that I am having is that I would instead like those values to be the SUM of the lookup in columns N through O and not just split individual values.

So my ideal output would have been:

```
15
```

Any ideas on this as to what I can change? I tried playing around with adding SUM into the formula but could never get it to calculate properly.

I obviously need this to work for values in column V that are in any specific order, as they will not always be in that order, though the values in Costs!N:O will always stay the same (as it is the lookup columns).

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance! I hope I have been clear enough, if not please do feel free to edit my question accordingly.

**ANSWER:**

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(SUM(vlookup(trim(split(V:V,",")),Costs!$N:$O,2,0))),"")
```

Thanks to Tom Sharpe for coming up with the solution to my problem! I simply edited his solution to handle blank values so the cell remains empty instead of throwing the dreaded "#ERROR!" message. All credit goes to him! :)

Comment: I couldn't work out why you were using SPLIT, as there don't seem to be any commas in column V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fine when I simplified it right down like this

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(vlookup(V1:V3,Costs!N:O,2,0)))
```

but like I say, I may be missing something with the use of SPLIT.

I have changed V:V to V1 to V3 because the VLOOKUP was failing on the empty cells in V4 etc.

After the edit to the question, have included SPLIT, but now this just works on a single cell and gives the answer 15:-

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(vlookup(trim(split(V1,",")),Costs!$N:$O,2,0)))
```

It can be pulled down for V2 etc.

Comment: Hey there Tom, thanks for your reply it is greatly appreciated! I am terribly sorry for missing out on that key component, I've updated my question accordingly. I hope that makes a bit more sense! :)

Comment: Tom, did you manage to get your latest edit working for you? As I've tried it and tried as is as well as trying to troubleshoot and no matter what I try I still get a #ERROR! Not sure perhaps if it is me not explaining clearly again, haha! The process should be that I have a bunch of values that are in the same line, comma-separated (like Apple, Banana, Carrot) and that has to be matched in a column that contains those values but they are each in a new cell (N1 = Apple, N2 = Banana, N3 = Carrot etc.) and adjacent to those cells in column O are the values in a single format (1, 2, 3 etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I think it's a locale problem. When I copied the formula back from my post I got the same sort of problem, but when I set my locale to UK and re-typed the formula it was OK. It seemed to be the quotation marks that were upsetting it.

Comment: That did it! Tom, you're a legend, and with a little tweaking to your provided solution (you save me hours of headaches and made all my suffering mean something) I have come up with a solution to keep the cells blank if they don't have any values so it doesn't spit out an error! I have added the solution as an edit to my question, credit you accordingly and marked your solution as the answer! Thank you, once again!!

Comment: Thank you for the comments, that's very nice of you (in spite of the fact that I made more problems for you with the quotes!)

Comment: It is honestly not a problem AT ALL. I am sure you know what it is like to get to the point where you have tried everything and simply hit a brick wall... You took down that wall for me and allowed me to progress on, and I've learnt a great deal in the process. So thank you once again! :)